# When to apply phong shading in volume data?

Tags: opengl, glsl, data-visualization, volume-rendering

I have a volume dataset, that I can render(this was part of a homework)
I have already implemented ray casting using front-to-back composition and I want to integrate phong-shading. For computing the gradient I use forward-difference-method.

I know I can estimate the gradient of a voxel texture coordinate with  the forward difference method.

My question would be, since phong-shading returns a color and front-to-back raycasting also returns a color, when do I apply the shading to the color of the ray function? After I have finalized my new color for a specific ray or while computing the color from the ray hit?
Maybe this piece of code helps to understand my problem. I have added comments on where I think I should implement phong shading.

```
void main(){
     if (raycast(t0,t1)) {

        float t = t0;
        for(float t =t0; t<t1;t+=stepsize){
              vec3 p = ray_o + ray_d * t;
              vec3 coord = worldToVolumeCoord(p, min_box, max_box);      
              float s = texture(tex_vol, coord).r;
              vec4 color = texture(tex_tf, s);
              if(color.a > 0){
                  // Front to back , when to apply shading?????
                  C = C + (1-A) * color.a * vec3(color);
                  A = A + (1-A) * color.a;
              }
             // vec3 Gradient = getGradient(tex_vol, coord, stepsize)
             // But how to apply Phong Shading?
        }
        // Apply phong here?
    }
}
```

Comment: Phong shading changes the *intensity* of a color, not the tone, mainly based in the normal at that fragment. I'd apply Phong *after* ray-casting is done.

Comment: The phong illumination model is a surface reflection model. It does not apply to volumes. You could apply it to an iso-surface of the volume, though. But then, you would not need the compositing. You could also do a mixture of both (iso-surface + volume rendering up to the surface).

Comment: @NicoSchertler Not sure how to reply to this. This was part of the homework. So you mean I dont apply the phong illumination model to the volume but to iso-surface? Isnt that exactly what I am trying to do? I'am creating a iso-surface with the help of compositing. Why wouldnt I need composition at all?

Comment: If you have an iso-surface, there is nothing to compose (you only care about the first intersection of the ray with the surface). For an iso-surface, you need an iso-value, which I do not see in your code. It is hard to help when it is unclear what kind of visualization you are after.

Comment: @NicoSchertler Then it is not a iso-surface. The goal is to implement volume ray casting on the gpu with compositing and then apply illumination in form of phong shading

Comment: Then we are back at square one. Where is the surface that you want to illuminate? Phong illumination only applies to surfaces. Btw, Phong illumination and Phong shading are two different things. The shading strategy refers to where you evaluate the illumination model and what you do with it.

Comment: @NicoSchertler Maybe we can move to chat? I think I have a bigger missunderstanding than I thought. The function raycast(t0,t1) is pseudocode for when the raycast hits something in the volume then t0 and t1 are the intersection points. So are the points I hit with raycasting not defining my surface? (It's a CT scan of a foot, as 3D Texture)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180367/discussion-between-nico-schertler-and-greedsin).